# How to check based on GPS coordinates if point is near a given path?

Tags: coordinate-system, algorithm

Path is just a straight line defined by coordinates of the beginning and end of it.

My coordinates are simply longitude and latitude of three points:

- start of the path
- end of the path
- my point (for which I want to check if it's near a given path)

Given that my paths are in the mountains I think the best would be to get a distance in the idealized 3D space.

I expect my point to be up to 25-50 meters away from the path.

Comment: what software do you plan on using? what are you looking to gather - distance from path, etc?

Comment: I'm not using any software at this moment - I'm about to write my own software. Yes - distance from the path would be great.
I'm not sure if this is important or no - but my paths are in the mountains (so start and end are always at different altitudes) - think ski/snowboard lifts.

Comment: What programming language? What GPS software? What format is your data in? You are missing a lot of details that would be helpful.  Please take the community [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and see the [help page on asking questions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)   As it stands, your question is too vague.

Comment: I have coordinates as longitude and latitude - so three coordinates, start of the line, end of the line, and my point. Language does not matter - I'm looking for a algorithm - which I will be able to convert to any language.

Comment: Do you want distance on a 2D plane, or distance in idealized 3D space (without a terrain model) or distance along the real topographic surface? What lengths do you plan to calculate (100km or 50m)?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to improve it in response to any requested clarifications.

Comment: Distance in the idealized 3D space probably would be optimal, but even 2D plan should be good to start with.

Comment: What is your intended output?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to review the [Paul Ramsey PostGIS Gotchas You Tube Video](https://youtu.be/GSuZP89UdGs?t=475).  The video link starts at the distance discussion. There are pitfalls with every coordinate system.  The thing that caught my eye along time ago when I saw a similar video is that a GPS point may not be under the line that your two other GPS points draw.